# GraalJS: How to pause a script or run it line by line?

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

Is it possible to pause execution of a js script at a specific line and resume it later?

Or even better, ask the engine to run only one line of JS and wait for instructions to proceed?

I want to allow a limited debugger-like functionality when running JS via GraalVM.